# cannot mount a hard drive

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

I have a second hard drive that has a partition for /home mounted on the first drive. yesterday, the booting failed because /home cannot be found. I run 'blkid' and see its uuid is gone. but when I run 'fdisk -l' I can see the drive.

I tried to manually mount it but it wouldn't recognize any the filesystem type. and 'dmesg|tail' showed can't find ext3/ext4 and etc.

I also run 'file -Ls /dev/sda1' and it gives '/dev/sda1: data'.

Is there a way that I can access the drive or just copy the data off the drive?

thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `blkid`?

Comment: When you try manually mounting it what is the error message?

Comment: blkid shows the uuid for the other hard drive.

Comment: I tried to mount it so I can get some important stuff off it. It was mount through fstab and it's not working any more.